# npx create-react-app frontend command encounters error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, authentication

**I want to create a frontend project using**

`npx create-react-app frontend`

encountered an error saying

> npm ERR! code ENOENT
> npm ERR! syscall lstat
> npm ERR! path C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm
> npm ERR! errno -4058
> npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, lstat 'C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm'
> npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
> npm ERR! enoent
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\npm-cache_logs\2024-03-06T09_13_21_921Z-debug-0.log

Tried browsing for answers but in browsing hell already.
I tried using `Vite` which is much easier but the folder structure of what I'm watching in YouTube is different so I get more confused.

Answer (score 3):

This error occurs because there isn't 'npm' folder in 'C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming' Folder in your computer.
I guess you change your computer name recently. Am I right?
To fix this error, you should copy 'npm' folder in 'C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming' Folder in your computer from others...
And then try again...

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 2):

Weird, but I fixed it by running the following command in the terminal:

```
npm install -g npm@latest
```